# Unsure of how to reference an element within a list to an if statement

Tags: python

```
for row in range(numLines):
    if row[intIdx](3) is not 'DEP':
        check_total += float(row[intIdx][2])
    else:
        deposit_total += float(row[intIdx][2])
```

I'm very green to python, coming from vb.net, so it may not make sense.

I have a list that has 4 elements per line with a comma delimiter. This block of code is supposed to run through each "row" and compare the 4th element with the parameter of the if statement, and to carry on whatever operation depending on the results.

I keep getting the 'int' object is not a subscriptable error, which I suspect that it might be more errors on top of this one.

I just need an explanation of what is going on and how I can improve the code so that my program can run properly.

I thank everyone for any input they can give me.

Comment: Can you plase post your input model?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/44fbf3d31ba01bb8a0b5


To make it easier to view, I put the code in github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looping through a range. numLines is either the size of a list or the length of an input file. Honestly I did not quite get your idea, but  I think that is what you are trying to do.

```
with open('Transactions.txt') as file:
 for line in file: 
     rowarray = line.split(',')  

     if rowarray[3] != 'DEP':
        check_total += float(rowarray[2])
     else:
        deposit_total += float(rowarray[2])
```

When you write

```
for i in range(nuList):
```

you are basically doing

```
for i in [1, 2, 3, ...., N]: # being N the size of your list
```

Therefor you are not looping through your data but rather through the range of indexes.

Comment: I got it! I was wondering, "but wouldn't the array change every time it went through the loop?" Well, once I move the calculations into the for line in file loop, it worked! Other than a few other stuff, this cleared up the confusion I was having.

Answer (score 0):

This line is your problem:

```
if row[intIdx](3) is not 'DEP':
```

You need to create an array from the row, currently it is just a string.  Here is the code:

```
for row in range(numLines):
    rowarray = row.split(',')
    if rowarray[3] != 'DEP':
        check_total += float(rowarray[2])
    else:
        deposit_total += float(rowarray[2])
```

Comment: I changed it up, but now I run into another problem with it starting at the if statement. "AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: you are looping through integers so you cannot split. @Crispybro you must add the source of your data, so that we can understand how to loop through  it

Comment: So int can't be split, but string can?

Comment: How do you imagine to split an integer?

Comment: (input model linked above)

Fair enough. I'm still learning all the stuff python can and cannot do, just as indention is **very** important compared to vb.net